# Select the next/prev mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I've written a MySQL statment to select the next item using the items created timestamp, but I have a problem with it when two or more items have the exact same timestamp. To make things more confusing the item ID and created dates are not always in order, see the dummy data below.

> ID | created
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   10 | 1289780100
>   11 | 1289780100
>   12 | 1289780100 <- current item
>   13 | 1289780100
>   14 | 1289780050
>   15 | 1289780150

I need a SQL statement that can select the prev & next item (two queries are fine) by created and then ID. I've tired a few different queries but either gets stuck in a loop or both 'prev' & 'next' are the same.

Thanks,
Owen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE created >= current_item_created AND ID >= current_item_ID
ORDER BY created ASC, ID ASC LIMIT 1,1

SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE created <= current_item_created AND ID <= current_item_ID
ORDER BY created DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: Thanks AndreKR, maybe I'm over complicating things but in some usual case the created dates may not be in order. (this is because items are added but not finished or published)  
Eg. If the current item was #14 in the table above i'd expect the previous to be nothing and and the next to be #10

Comment: @Owen: then compare `created` field with current item created.

Comment: Then it is indeed a bit more complicated, but I think those (edited) queries should do it.

Answer (score 2):

To get prev_id:

```
SELECT   
  t1.id, t1.name, t1.prev as prev_id  
FROM   
(SELECT mt.id, mt.name, @prev_id as prev, @prev_id := id   
FROM `main_table` mt, (SELECT @prev_id:=0) ni   
ORDER BY name ASC) as t1;
```

To get next_id - just change ordering

[Here is full example](http://inetstd.blogspot.com/2011/06/mysql-get-nextprev-id-with-exact.html)